# Spring data MongoDB exclude fields from findAll method with predicate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to be able to exclude really heavy objects from a MongoDB document

I managed to override the default `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method:

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "?0")
fun findAllAndIncludeFields(includeFields: Map<String, Int>, pageable: Pageable): Page<MyEntity>
```

But now I would also like to override another signature of the `findAll()` method which takes `querydsl Predicate` param

```
Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

I can not find a way to write a method which will execute the predicate, implement the pagination and also exclude some fields from the response object (apply mongodb projection)

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: would it be feasible to exclude it from your entity rather than the query

Comment: I will include it on demand

Comment: You can include and exclude fields using the query _projection_.

Comment: I know that and the question was how to combine queryDsl and queryProjection in spring data